# How can I update a value without resetting it?

Tags: android

I'm trying to work on a simple budget application but am having issues with updating the budget amount. On my Main screen the user can click on a button that will take them to a different activity where they can add income to their budget. Once they press the add income button, it will take them back to Main and display their current budget. The first time money is added to the budget it works fine, however, if I want to add more money, the budget amount gets replaced with the new input instead of incrementing the amount that was already there. Here is the code for Main:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        float cashEarned  = getIntent().getFloatExtra("income",0);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentBudget);
        String budget = "" + cashEarned;
        textView.setText(budget);


    }

    public void expenseClick(View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExpensesActivity.class));

    }

    public void incomeClick(View v){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,IncomeActivity.class));
            }

    public void chartClick(View v){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChartsActivity.class));
    }

    }
```

The layout for Main:

This is my code for adding money to the budget:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class IncomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_income);

        backToMainMenu();
    }

    private void backToMainMenu() {

        final EditText editTextIncome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.moneyEarned);


        Button incomeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addIncomeScreen3);
        incomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float income = Float.parseFloat(editTextIncome.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("income",income);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can add to my current budget without replacing it every time a new amount is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is essentially not right. You keep on creating an `IncomeActivity` from the `MainActivity`. Once done with the `IncomeActivity`, you create another `MainActivity`. So, basically you keep on creating activities.

What you should do is create an `IncomeActivity`, then *set the result* and `finish` the `IncomeActivity`. The `MainActivity` will then be able to read the results. This way you will not create unnecessary `Activity` instances.

You should use the startActivityForResult method for scenarios like this. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) is the documentation on that.

Answer (score 1):

Check intent value exist or not `if(getIntent().getExtra() != null){`

Add following code to main activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(getIntent().getExtra() != null){
           float cashEarned  = getIntent().getFloatExtra("income",0);

        TextView textView =     (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentBudget);
        String budget = "" + cashEarned;
        textView.setText(budget);
      }

    }

    public void expenseClick(View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExpensesActivity.class));

    }

    public void incomeClick(View v){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,IncomeActivity.class));
            }

    public void chartClick(View v){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChartsActivity.class));
    }

    }
```